# PHP Fatal Error won't let me update Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a single line of code that's stopping me from upgrading my site's PHP. I'm not a programmer, but I'm hoping that since it's only one line, it might be something I can fix. The error is coming up as "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function" and is citing the following line of code as the culprit:

```php
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 8;' ), 20 );
```

Anyone have any idea of how to get this working properly?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php - removed as of PHP 8

Comment: `PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function`...this clearly isn't the full error message, it's missing the bit which tells you _which_ function is undefined. Luckily it was easy to guess, but in future please don't truncate, abbreviate, paraphrase or otherwise alter error messages when reporting them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', static function ( $per_page ) {
    return 8;
}, 20 );
```